# Malfunction when loading preamble code using \include{}

Tags: tikz-pgf, include, paths, preamble

I am trying to load a piece of code using `\include{file}`. This code uses `tikz` to create fancy chapters. The weird thing is that when I load my code, the `\chaptername` gets cut(after running the code twice), like is shown in the image below.

[image]

However if I directly put the code in my preamble and run it twice, it works fine!

[image]

I cannot think of any logical reason for this malfunction. Any idea on what might be wrong and how can it be fixed?

My code is

**`main.tex`**

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{etex}%Makes able the use of many packages
\include{Preamble/fancyChapter}

\begin{document}

  \chapter{rkbnjg}
  %\eng{Hello world}, Γεια σου κόσμε\\

\end{document}
```

**`fancyChapter.tex`**

```
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepgflibrary{qrr.shapes.openrectangle}

\definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{0,173,239}
\definecolor{myblueii}{RGB}{63,200,244}
\definecolor{myblueiii}{RGB}{199,234,253}

\tikzset{
mynode/.style={
  rounded corners=30pt,
  shape=open rectangle,
  open rectangle fill=myblueii,
  open rectangle sides=#1,
  }
}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\sffamily}
  {}
  {20pt}
  {%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node[
    anchor=west,
    rectangle,
    minimum height=4cm,
    text width=\paperwidth,
    xshift=-\the\dimexpr\oddsidemargin+1in\relax,
    outer sep=0pt,
    fill=myblueiii] (titlerect) {};
  \node[
    anchor=south west,
    xshift=2cm,
    text width=\textwidth] 
    at ([yshift=5pt]titlerect.south west) {\fontsize{30}{36}\selectfont#1};
  \node[
    mynode=nw,
    anchor=south east,
    fill=myblueii,
    inner xsep=1.5cm,
    outer sep=0pt,
    font=\color{white},
    minimum height=30pt] 
    at (current page.east|-titlerect.north)
     {\bfseries\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}\ \thechapter};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\sffamily}
  {}
  {20pt}
  {%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node[
    anchor=west,
    rectangle,
    minimum height=4cm,
    text width=\paperwidth,
    xshift=-\the\dimexpr\oddsidemargin+1in\relax,
    outer sep=0pt,
    fill=myblueiii] (titlerect) {};
  \node[
    anchor=south west,
    xshift=2cm,
    text width=\textwidth] 
    at (titlerect.south west) {\Huge#1};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{-20pt}{60pt}

\usepackage[margin=2.8cm]{geometry}

\setlength\beforeepigraphskip{1.5\baselineskip}
\setlength\afterepigraphskip{2\baselineskip}
\setlength\epigraphwidth{6.8cm}
\setlength\epigraphrule{0.1pt}
\renewcommand\epigraphsize{\large}
\renewcommand\textflush{flushright}

\let\oldepigraph\epigraph \renewcommand\epigraph[2]{%
  \oldepigraph{\color{blue}\itshape #1}{#2}}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\newcommand\DoPToC{%
\startcontents\printcontents{}{1}{\noindent{\color{blue}\rule{\textwidth}{.5pt}}\par\medskip}}
\usepackage{xpatch}
```

Comment: You can't use `include` in the preamble, use `input` instead. `include` does more stuff than directly copying the filecontent, for example it issues a `clearpage` IIRC.

Comment: @JuriRobl : Well...That really fixed it, but I can't see how... I know about the `clearpage` but I am only using `include` to load code in the preamble, so as to have it more elegant.

Comment: Why is `include` more elegant than `input`?

Comment: @JuriRobl : No, no, no! You misunderstood me! I wanted to use `include/input` so as not to have a big preamble. It wasn't a comparison between `input` and `include`. I just didn't think of `\clearpage`.

Comment: Ah ok. That makes sense ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `\include` in the preamble, use `\input` instead.

`\include` does more stuff than directly copying the filecontent, for example it issues a `\clearpage`, which obviously doesn't belong in the preamble.

Another possibility would be to write a new package and load it with `usepackage`, or write a new class.